# Phusion Passenger on Ubuntu not seeing plugin in vendors directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, phusion

Phusion Passenger, running on Ubuntu Hardy Heron, is bombing on a require 'lingua/en/readability'. The plugin is installed in the plugins directory and works fine with script/server, just not Passenger.

Error Message:

source file that the application requires, is missing.

```
*
  It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
*
  A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
```

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
    no such file to load -- lingua/en/readability (MissingSourceFile)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the plugin needs to be installed on the server. It won't work from a Rails plugin directory as-is.